# Entity Framework Code First - Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_CRProviders'

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have some urgent issue which I could not find answer for across the web.

I am using CodeFirst EF 4.3.1 and I am getting an error:
`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_T_CRProviders'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_CRProviders'.`

My code is:

Models:

```
public enum CRProviderEnums
{
    PE_Abcd = 0,
    PE_Efgh
}

[Table("T_CRProviders")]
public class CRProvider
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Enum { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("T_CRSupportedResources")]
public class CRSupportedResource
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SupportedResourceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public CRProvider Provider { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class RSContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CRProvider> CRProviders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CRSupportedResource> CRSupportedResources { get; set; }
}
```

Table T_CRProviders looks like this: `Enum (PK), Name`

Table T_CRSupportedResources looks like this: `SupportedResourceId (PK), Provider_Enum (FK).`

In the database table T_CRProviders I already have a provider with the following values:

```
Enum: 0 (which is PE_Abcd)
Name: "PE_Abcd"
```

Now my main() calls a method AddSupportedResource. This method adds to table T_CRSupportedResources a new CRSupportedResource which refers to provider 0 (PE_Abcd). The method looks like this:

```
public void AddSupportedResource()
    {
        CRSupportedResource supportedResource = new CRSupportedResource()
        {
            SupportedResourceId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Provider = new CRProvider()
            {
                Enum = (int)CRProviderEnums.PE_Abcd,
                Name = "PE_Abcd"
            }
        };

        using (RSContext myContext = new RSContext())
        {
            myContext.CRSupportedResources.Add(supportedResource);

            myContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I expect that this method will leave table T_CRProviders untouched, and add a new row to table T_CRSupportedResources which will look like this:

```
SupportedResourceId: DE532083-68CF-484A-8D2B-606BC238AB61
Provider_Enum (FK): 0 (which is PE_Abcd).
```

Instead, upon SaveChanges, Entity framework also tries to add Provider to the T_CRProviders table, and since such a provider already exists it throws the following exception:

```
An error occurred while updating the entries.

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_T_CRProviders'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_CRProviders'.

The statement has been terminated.
```

**My question:**

How can I instruct the EF not to update table `T_CRProviders` upon updating table `T_CRSupportedResources`?

Btw, in the SQL Server I see that table `T_CRSupportedResources` has a foreign key named `FK_RW_TCRSupportedCloudResources_RW_TCRCloudProviders_Provider_Enum` and its Update Rule has the value of `No Action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to do this.

See the answer to my question in the following link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/62f3e5bc-c972-4622-b830-e7d7fe710101

Comment: It is another **worse** solution because you are doing additional roundtrip to database to get record you already know ...

Answer (score 6):

> I expect that this method will leave table T_CRProviders untouched,
>   and add a new row to table T_CRSupportedResources

No it will not happen. You are creating detached entity graph consisting of existing entity a and new entity. EF doesn't know about the existence of your entity until you inform it about it - there are no DB queries validating existence performed by EF on behind.

If you call `Add` method all entities in your entity graph are added as new. If you don't want to insert all of them you can start with using `Attach` and manually change state for new ones. For example like:

```
myContext.CRSupportedResources.Attach(supportedResource);
myContext.Entry(supportedResource).State = EntityState.Added;
```